# How to delete a file from specific location in java

Tags: java, file

I know how to delete a file if file path is given.

```
File file = new File(“C:\\Users\\customname\\sample.txt”);
file.delete();
```

In the above path of customname is not given and if my code should work for any given customname, what needs to be done?

Basically my path should be `C:\\Users\\..\\sample.txt`

Those .. can be my name or other person name based on whose machine code is running

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your question is about getting username in windows, then try

```
String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
File file = new File(“C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\sample.txt”); 
file.delete();
```

Edit: fixed backslashes.

Comment: Backslashes will not work here without escaping them.